# Mismatched braces in Edge Animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, adobe, adobe-edge

Something happened to my code in Animate. Exact error is "Mismatched braces" in the end of document, line 882, })(window.jQuery || AdobeEdge.$, AdobeEdge, "EDGE-3775642");

How can i fix this? I understand, that the problem is with unclosed bracket, but how can I find it?

```html
/***********************
* Adobe Edge Animate Composition Actions
*
* Edit this file with caution, being careful to preserve 
* function signatures and comments starting with 'Edge' to maintain the 
* ability to interact with these actions from within Adobe Edge Animate
*
***********************/
(function($, Edge, compId){
var Composition = Edge.Composition, Symbol = Edge.Symbol; // aliases for commonly used Edge classes

   //Edge symbol: 'stage'
   (function(symbolName) {
      
      
      

      

      Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, symbolName, "${button1}", "mouseover", function(sym, e) {
         // insert code to be run when the mouse hovers over the object
         sym.getSymbol("button1").play();
         
         sym.getSymbol("line1").play();
         // Show an element 
         sym.$("line1").show();
         sym.getSymbol("cont1").play();
         
         // Show an element 
         sym.$("cont1").show();
         
         
         
         
         
         
         
         // Hide an element 
         sym.$("Text9").hide();

      });
      //Edge binding endSymbol.bindElementAction(compId, symbolName, "${button1}", "mouseleave", function(sym, e) {
         // insert code to be run when the mouse leaves an element
         
         sym.getSymbol("line1").stop();
         
         sym.getSymbol("line1").stop();
         
         // Hide an element 
         
         // Hide an element 
         sym.$("line1").hide();
         
         
         
         
         // Hide an element 
         sym.$("cont1").hide();
         setTimeout(delay, 1500);
         

      });
      //Edge binding end

      

      Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, symbolName, "${bitton2}", "mouseover", function(sym, e) {
         // insert code to be run when the mouse hovers over the object
         sym.getSymbol("bitton2").getSymbol("button15Copy").play();
         
         
         
         sym.getSymbol("line2").play();
         
         // Show an element 
         sym.$("line2").show();
         
         
         
         sym.getSymbol("cont2").play();
         
         // Show an element 
         sym.$("cont2").show();

      });
      //Edge binding end

      Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, symbolName, "${button3}", "mouseover", function(sym, e) {
         // insert code to be run when the mouse hovers over the object
         sym.getSymbol("button3").getSymbol("button15Copy2").play();
         
         sym.getSymbol("line3").play();
         sym.getSymbol("cont3").play();
         
         // Show an element 
         sym.$("cont3").show();
         
         
         // Show an element 
         sym.$("line3").show();
         

      });
      //Edge binding end

      Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, symbolName, "${button4}", "mouseover", function(sym, e) {
         // insert code to be run when the mouse hovers over the object
         sym.getSymbol("cont4").play();
         
         // Hide an element 
         sym.$("cont4").hide();
         
         // Show an element 
         sym.$("cont4").show();
         
         sym.getSymbol("button4").getSymbol("button15Copy3").play();
         
         sym.getSymbol("line4").play();
         
         // Show an element 
         sym.$("line4").show();
         

      });
      //Edge binding end

      Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, symbolName, "${button5}", "mouseover", function(sym, e) {
         // insert code to be run when the mouse hovers over the object
         sym.getSymbol("cont5").play();
         
         
         
         // Show an element 
         sym.$("cont5").show();
         
         sym.getSymbol("button5").getSymbol("button15Copy4").play();
         
         sym.getSymbol("line5").play();
         
         // Show an element 
         sym.$("line5").show();
         

      });
      //Edge binding end

      Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, symbolName, "${button6}", "mouseover", function(sym, e) {
         // insert code to be run when the mouse hovers over the object
         sym.getSymbol("button6").getSymbol("button15Copy5").play();
         
         sym.getSymbol("line6").play();
         sym.getSymbol("cont6").play();
          
          // Show an element 
          sym.$("cont6").show();
          
         
         // Show an element 
         sym.$("line6").show();
         

      });
      //Edge binding end

      Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, symbolName, "${button7}", "mouseover", function(sym, e) {
         // insert code to be run when the mouse hovers over the object
         sym.getSymbol("button7").getSymbol("button15Copy6").play();
         
         sym.getSymbol("line7").play();
         // Show an element 
         sym.$("cont7").show();
         
         sym.getSymbol("cont7").play();
         
         
         // Show an element 
         sym.$("line7").show();
         

      });
      //Edge binding end

      Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, symbolName, "${button8}", "mouseover", function(sym, e) {
         // insert code to be run when the mouse hovers over the object
         sym.getSymbol("cont8").play();
         
         // Show an element 
         sym.$("cont8").show();
         
         sym.getSymbol("button8").getSymbol("button15Copy7").play();
         
         sym.getSymbol("line8").play();
         
         
         // Show an element 
         sym.$("line8").show();
         
         

      });
      //Edge binding end

      Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, symbolName, "${button9}", "mouseover", function(sym, e) {
         // insert code to be run when the mouse hovers over the object
         sym.getSymbol("cont9").play();
         
         // Show an element 
         sym.$("cont9").show();
         
         sym.getSymbol("button9").getSymbol("button15Copy8").play();
         
         sym.getSymbol("line9").play();
         
         // Show an element 
         sym.$("line9").show();
         

      });
      //Edge binding end

      Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, symbolName, "${button10}", "mouseover", function(sym, e) {
         // insert code to be run when the mouse hovers over the object
         sym.getSymbol("cont10").play();
         
         // Hide an element 
         
         // Show an element 
         sym.$("cont10").show();
         
         
         sym.getSymbol("button10").getSymbol("button15Copy10").play();
         
         sym.getSymbol("line10").play();
         
         // Show an element 
         sym.$("line10").show();
         

      });
      //Edge binding end

      Symbol.bindTriggerAction(compId, symbolName, "Default Timeline", 0, function(sym, e) {
         // insert code here
         
         
         
         
         sym.getSymbol("line1").stop();

      });
      //Edge binding end

      Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, symbolName, "${line1}", "mouseleave", function(sym, e) {
         
         

      });
      //Edge binding end

      Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, symbolName, "${line1}", "mouseout", function(sym, e) {
         
         

      });
      //Edge binding end

      Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, symbolName, "${bitton2}", "mouseout", function(sym, e) {
         // insert code to be run when the mouse is moved off the object
         sym.getSymbol("line2").stop();
         
         // Hide an element 
         sym.$("line2").hide();
         
         
         sym.getSymbol("cont2").stop();
         
         // Hide an element 
         sym.$("cont2").hide();

      });
      //Edge binding end

      Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, symbolName, "${button3}", "mouseout", function(sym, e) {
         // insert code to be run when the mouse is moved off the object
         sym.getSymbol("line3").stop();
         
         // Hide an element 
         sym.$("line3").hide();
         
         sym.getSymbol("cont3").stop();
         
         // Hide an element 
         sym.$("cont3").hide();
         

      });
      //Edge binding end

      Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, symbolName, "${button4}", "mouseout", function(sym, e) {
         // insert code to be run when the mouse is moved off the object
         sym.getSymbol("cont4").stop();
         
         // Hide an element 
         sym.$("cont4").hide();
         
         sym.getSymbol("line4").stop();
         // Hide an element 
         sym.$("line4").hide();
         
         

      });
      //Edge binding end

      Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, symbolName, "${button5}", "mouseout", function(sym, e) {
         // insert code to be run when the mouse is moved off the object
         sym.getSymbol("cont5").stop();
         
         // Hide an element 
         sym.$("cont5").hide();
         
         sym.getSymbol("line5").stop();
         
         // Hide an element 
         sym.$("line5").hide();
         

      });
      //Edge binding end

      Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, symbolName, "${button6}", "mouseout", function(sym, e) {
         // insert code to be run when the mouse is moved off the object
         sym.getSymbol("line6").stop();
         
         // Hide an element 
         // Hide an element 
         sym.$("cont6").hide();
         
         sym.$("line6").hide();
         
         sym.getSymbol("cont6").stop();
         
         // Show an element 
         
         

      });
      //Edge binding end

      Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, symbolName, "${button7}", "mouseout", function(sym, e) {
         // insert code to be run when the mouse is moved off the object
         sym.getSymbol("line7").stop();
         
         // Hide an element 
         sym.$("line7").hide();
         
         sym.getSymbol("cont7").stop();
         
         // Hide an element 
         sym.$("cont7").hide();
         

      });
      //Edge binding end

      Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, symbolName, "${button8}", "mouseout", function(sym, e) {
         // insert code to be run when the mouse is moved off the object
         sym.getSymbol("cont8").stop();
         
         // Hide an element 
         sym.$("cont8").hide();
         
         sym.getSymbol("line8").stop();
         
         // Hide an element 
         sym.$("line8").hide();
         

      });
      //Edge binding end

      Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, symbolName, "${button9}", "mouseout", function(sym, e) {
         // insert code to be run when the mouse is moved off the object
         sym.getSymbol("cont9").stop();
         
         // Hide an element 
         sym.$("cont9").hide();
         
         sym.getSymbol("line9").stop();
         
         // Hide an element 
         sym.$("line9").hide();
         

      });
      //Edge binding end

      Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, symbolName, "${button10}", "mouseout", function(sym, e) {
         // insert code to be run when the mouse is moved off the object
         sym.getSymbol("cont10").stop();
         
         // Hide an element 
         sym.$("cont10").hide();
         
         sym.getSymbol("line10").play();
         
         // Hide an element 
         sym.$("line10").hide();
         

      });
      //Edge binding end

      Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, symbolName, "${Stage}", "mouseover", function(sym, e) {
         // insert code to be run when the mouse hovers over the object
         
      });
      //Edge binding end

   })("stage");
   //Edge symbol end:'stage'

   //=========================================================
   
   //Edge symbol: 'Button1'
   (function(symbolName) {   
   
   })("Button1");
   //Edge symbol end:'Button1'

   //=========================================================
   
   //Edge symbol: 'button1'
   (function(symbolName) {   
   
      Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, symbolName, "${buttons}", "mouseover", function(sym, e) {
         // insert code to be run when the mouse hovers over the object
         
      });
      //Edge binding end

   })("button1");
   //Edge symbol end:'button1'

   //=========================================================
   
   //Edge symbol: 'caontainer1'
   (function(symbolName) {   
   
   })("caontainer1");
   //Edge symbol end:'caontainer1'

   //=========================================================
   
   //Edge symbol: 'bitton2'
   (function(symbolName) {   
   
      Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, symbolName, "${button15Copy}", "mouseover", function(sym, e) {
         // insert code to be run when the mouse hovers over the object
         sym.getSymbol("button15").play();
         
         
         // Show an element 
         sym.getSymbol("caontainer1").$("cont1").show();
         
         sym.getSymbol("caontainer1").play();

      });
      //Edge binding end

      Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, symbolName, "${button15Copy}", "mouseleave", function(sym, e) {
         // insert code to be run when the mouse leaves an element
         sym.getSymbol("caontainer1").stop();
         

      });
      //Edge binding end

   })("bitton2");
   //Edge symbol end:'bitton2'

   //=========================================================
   
   //Edge symbol: 'button3'
   (function(symbolName) {   
   
      Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, symbolName, "${button15Copy2}", "mouseover", function(sym, e) {
         // insert code to be run when the mouse hovers over the object
         sym.getSymbol("button15").play();
         
         
         // Show an element 
         sym.getSymbol("caontainer1").$("cont1").show();
         
         sym.getSymbol("caontainer1").play();

      });
      //Edge binding end

      Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, symbolName, "${button15Copy2}", "mouseleave", function(sym, e) {
         // insert code to be run when the mouse leaves an element
         sym.getSymbol("caontainer1").stop();
         

      });
      //Edge binding end

   })("button3");
   //Edge symbol end:'button3'

   //=========================================================
   
   //Edge symbol: 'button4'
   (function(symbolName) {   
   
      Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, symbolName, "${button15Copy3}", "mouseover", function(sym, e) {
         // insert code to be run when the mouse hovers over the object
         sym.getSymbol("button15").play();
         
         
         // Show an element 
         sym.getSymbol("caontainer1").$("cont1").show();
         
         sym.getSymbol("caontainer1").play();

      });
      //Edge binding end

      Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, symbolName, "${button15Copy3}", "mouseleave", function(sym, e) {
         // insert code to be run when the mouse leaves an element
         sym.getSymbol("caontainer1").stop();
         

      });
      //Edge binding end

   })("button4");
   //Edge symbol end:'button4'

   //=========================================================
   
   //Edge symbol: 'button5'
   (function(symbolName) {   
   
      Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, symbolName, "${button15Copy4}", "mouseover", function(sym, e) {
         // insert code to be run when the mouse hovers over the object
         sym.getSymbol("button15").play();
         
         
         // Show an element 
         sym.getSymbol("caontainer1").$("cont1").show();
         
         sym.getSymbol("caontainer1").play();

      });
      //Edge binding end

      Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, symbolName, "${button15Copy4}", "mouseleave", function(sym, e) {
         // insert code to be run when the mouse leaves an element
         sym.getSymbol("caontainer1").stop();
         

      });
      //Edge binding end

   })("button5");
   //Edge symbol end:'button5'

   //=========================================================
   
   //Edge symbol: 'button6'
   (function(symbolName) {   
   
      Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, symbolName, "${button15Copy5}", "mouseover", function(sym, e) {
         // insert code to be run when the mouse hovers over the object
         sym.getSymbol("button15").play();
         
         
         // Show an element 
         sym.getSymbol("caontainer1").$("cont1").show();
         
         sym.getSymbol("caontainer1").play();

      });
      //Edge binding end

      Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, symbolName, "${button15Copy5}", "mouseleave", function(sym, e) {
         // insert code to be run when the mouse leaves an element
         sym.getSymbol("caontainer1").stop();
         

      });
      //Edge binding end

   })("button6");
   //Edge symbol end:'button6'

   //=========================================================
   
   //Edge symbol: 'button7'
   (function(symbolName) {   
   
      Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, symbolName, "${button15Copy6}", "mouseover", function(sym, e) {
         // insert code to be run when the mouse hovers over the object
         sym.getSymbol("button15").play();
         
         
         // Show an element 
         sym.getSymbol("caontainer1").$("cont1").show();
         
         sym.getSymbol("caontainer1").play();

      });
      //Edge binding end

      Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, symbolName, "${button15Copy6}", "mouseleave", function(sym, e) {
         // insert code to be run when the mouse leaves an element
         sym.getSymbol("caontainer1").stop();
         

      });
      //Edge binding end

   })("button7");
   //Edge symbol end:'button7'

   //=========================================================
   
   //Edge symbol: 'button8'
   (function(symbolName) {   
   
      Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, symbolName, "${button15Copy7}", "mouseover", function(sym, e) {
         // insert code to be run when the mouse hovers over the object
         sym.getSymbol("button15").play();
         
         
         // Show an element 
         sym.getSymbol("caontainer1").$("cont1").show();
         
         sym.getSymbol("caontainer1").play();

      });
      //Edge binding end

      Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, symbolName, "${button15Copy7}", "mouseleave", function(sym, e) {
         // insert code to be run when the mouse leaves an element
         sym.getSymbol("caontainer1").stop();
         

      });
      //Edge binding end

   })("button8");
   //Edge symbol end:'button8'

   //=========================================================
   
   //Edge symbol: 'button9'
   (function(symbolName) {   
   
      Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, symbolName, "${button15Copy8}", "mouseover", function(sym, e) {
         // insert code to be run when the mouse hovers over the object
         sym.getSymbol("button15").play();
         
         
         // Show an element 
         sym.getSymbol("caontainer1").$("cont1").show();
         
         sym.getSymbol("caontainer1").play();

      });
      //Edge binding end

      Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, symbolName, "${button15Copy8}", "mouseleave", function(sym, e) {
         // insert code to be run when the mouse leaves an element
         sym.getSymbol("caontainer1").stop();
         

      });
      //Edge binding end

   })("button9");
   //Edge symbol end:'button9'

   //=========================================================
   
   //Edge symbol: 'button10'
   (function(symbolName) {   
   
      Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, symbolName, "${button15Copy10}", "mouseover", function(sym, e) {
         // insert code to be run when the mouse hovers over the object
         sym.getSymbol("button15").play();
         
         
         // Show an element 
         sym.getSymbol("caontainer1").$("cont1").show();
         
         sym.getSymbol("caontainer1").play();

      });
      //Edge binding end

      Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, symbolName, "${button15Copy10}", "mouseleave", function(sym, e) {
         // insert code to be run when the mouse leaves an element
         sym.getSymbol("caontainer1").stop();
         

      });
      //Edge binding end

   })("button10");
   //Edge symbol end:'button10'

   //=========================================================
   
   //Edge symbol: 'lines'
   (function(symbolName) {   
   
   })("lines");
   //Edge symbol end:'lines'

   //=========================================================
   
   //Edge symbol: 'line1'
   (function(symbolName) {   
   
   })("line1");
   //Edge symbol end:'line1'

   //=========================================================
   
   //Edge symbol: 'line2'
   (function(symbolName) {   
   
   })("line2");
   //Edge symbol end:'line2'

   //=========================================================
   
   //Edge symbol: 'line3'
   (function(symbolName) {   
   
   })("line3");
   //Edge symbol end:'line3'

   //=========================================================
   
   //Edge symbol: 'line'
   (function(symbolName) {   
   
   })("line");
   //Edge symbol end:'line'

   //=========================================================
   
   //Edge symbol: 'line5'
   (function(symbolName) {   
   
   })("line5");
   //Edge symbol end:'line5'

   //=========================================================
   
   //Edge symbol: 'line6'
   (function(symbolName) {   
   
   })("line6");
   //Edge symbol end:'line6'

   //=========================================================
   
   //Edge symbol: 'line7'
   (function(symbolName) {   
   
   })("line7");
   //Edge symbol end:'line7'

   //=========================================================
   
   //Edge symbol: 'line8'
   (function(symbolName) {   
   
   })("line8");
   //Edge symbol end:'line8'

   //=========================================================
   
   //Edge symbol: 'line9'
   (function(symbolName) {   
   
   })("line9");
   //Edge symbol end:'line9'

   //=========================================================
   
   //Edge symbol: 'line10'
   (function(symbolName) {   
   
   })("line10");
   //Edge symbol end:'line10'

   //=========================================================
   
   //Edge symbol: 'cont1'
   (function(symbolName) {   
   
   })("cont1");
   //Edge symbol end:'cont1'

   //=========================================================
   
   //Edge symbol: 'cont2'
   (function(symbolName) {   
   
   })("cont2");
   //Edge symbol end:'cont2'

   //=========================================================
   
   //Edge symbol: 'cont3'
   (function(symbolName) {   
   
   })("cont3");
   //Edge symbol end:'cont3'

   //=========================================================
   
   //Edge symbol: 'cont4'
   (function(symbolName) {   
   
   })("cont4");
   //Edge symbol end:'cont4'

   //=========================================================
   
   //Edge symbol: 'cont5'
   (function(symbolName) {   
   
   })("cont5");
   //Edge symbol end:'cont5'

   //=========================================================
   
   //Edge symbol: 'cont6'
   (function(symbolName) {   
   
   })("cont6");
   //Edge symbol end:'cont6'

   //=========================================================
   
   //Edge symbol: 'cont7'
   (function(symbolName) {   
   
   })("cont7");
   //Edge symbol end:'cont7'

   //=========================================================
   
   //Edge symbol: 'cont8'
   (function(symbolName) {   
   
   })("cont8");
   //Edge symbol end:'cont8'

   //=========================================================
   
   //Edge symbol: 'cont9'
   (function(symbolName) {   
   
   })("cont9");
   //Edge symbol end:'cont9'

   //=========================================================
   
   //Edge symbol: 'cont10'
   (function(symbolName) {   
   
   })("cont10");
   //Edge symbol end:'cont10'

})(window.jQuery || AdobeEdge.$, AdobeEdge, "EDGE-3775642");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
//Edge binding endSymbol.bindElementAction(compId, symbolName, "${button1}", "mouseleave", function(sym, e) {
```

`endSymbol.bindElementAction` is supposed to be on a new line, so it starts another function call, not part of the comment. So it should look like this:

```
//Edge binding 
endSymbol.bindElementAction(compId, symbolName, "${button1}", "mouseleave", function(sym, e) {
```

Comment: God bless, you, Barmar